# WARNING: Base.Dates is deprecated, run `using Dates` instead in module Base in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to resolve this issue when converting from Julia v0.6 to v0.7. I am already doing `using Dates` in the top of my file.

```
WARNING: Base.Dates is deprecated, run `using Dates` instead  in module Base
```

I do not have a Dates module anywhere in my code.  Any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you use any date or time related function in your code? Have you tried adding `using Dates` to top of your code and then restarting Julia?

Comment: Yes, I am.  It said before: WARNING: Base.Dates is deprecated, run `using Dates` instead  in module xxxxx, however now it says WARNING: Base.Dates is deprecated, run `using Dates` instead  in module Base.... I don't have a module called Base, and I already added using Dates to the top of xxxxx.

Comment: Just to make sure did you restart Julia after doing that?

Comment: I restart it after every command I do!

Comment: Does the warning give you the line of code or stack trace? If it does not, try starting julia with `--depwarn=error` option to make such warnings an error and to get the line of code that causes the warning.

Comment: How do I start Julia with that code? I am not familiar.  Do you mean add it to my startup.jl file?

Comment: Does your code contain something like `Dates.`? If so, you can remove them (just have function calls without `Dates. `) since you already have `using Dates`.

Comment: while starting julia repl write `julia --depwarn=error`.

Comment: I tried: julia> --depwarn=error
ERROR: syntax: invalid operator "--"

Comment: I use "Dates." over 100 times in my project, so I would prefer to keep it in if possible, but I will remove it if its a must.

Comment: I tried removing all ".Dates".... this does not resolve the issue!

Comment: you should run the command outside julia to start it. Open a terminal and write the command to start julia repl.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I will give it a try.